# Is there a way that I can pass a file (FASTA) to an array in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, pattern-matching, readfile, fasta

I'm using the [KMP algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/) using C++ for pattern searching in a FASTA file.

**KMP algorithm:**

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
  
void computeLPSArray(char* pat, int M, int* lps);
  
// Prints occurrences of txt[] in pat[]
void KMPSearch(char* pat, char* txt)
{
    int M = strlen(pat);
    int N = strlen(txt);
  
    // create lps[] that will hold the longest prefix suffix
    // values for pattern
    int lps[M];
  
    // Preprocess the pattern (calculate lps[] array)
    computeLPSArray(pat, M, lps);
  
    int i = 0; // index for txt[]
    int j = 0; // index for pat[]
    while (i < N) {
        if (pat[j] == txt[i]) {
            j++;
            i++;
        }
  
        if (j == M) {
            printf("Found pattern at index %d ", i - j);
            j = lps[j - 1];
        }
  
        // mismatch after j matches
        else if (i < N && pat[j] != txt[i]) {
            // Do not match lps[0..lps[j-1]] characters,
            // they will match anyway
            if (j != 0)
                j = lps[j - 1];
            else
                i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
  
// Fills lps[] for given patttern pat[0..M-1]
void computeLPSArray(char* pat, int M, int* lps)
{
    // length of the previous longest prefix suffix
    int len = 0;
  
    lps[0] = 0; // lps[0] is always 0
  
    // the loop calculates lps[i] for i = 1 to M-1
    int i = 1;
    while (i < M) {
        if (pat[i] == pat[len]) {
            len++;
            lps[i] = len;
            i++;
        }
        else // (pat[i] != pat[len])
        {
            // This is tricky. Consider the example.
            // AAACAAAA and i = 7. The idea is similar
            // to search step.
            if (len != 0) {
                len = lps[len - 1];
  
                // Also, note that we do not increment
                // i here
            }
            else // if (len == 0)
            {
                lps[i] = 0;
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
  
// Driver program to test above function
int main()
{
    char txt[] = "ABABDABACDABABCABAB";
    char pat[] = "ABABCABAB";
    KMPSearch(pat, txt);
    return 0;
}
```

So I want to modify the above code so that I can pass an input file in place of

```cpp
char txt[] = "ABABDABACDABABCABAB";
```

Similarly, for

```cpp
char pat[] = "ABABCABAB";
```

**Input file - 1. some_data_file.fasta**

```
>3a073269-a0b6-436a-a219-4130fcd3b9dc
TGTTGTACTTCGTTCAGTTACGTATTGCTGTTTTCCGCATTTATCGTGAAACGCTTTCGCGTTTTCGTGCGCCCGCTTCTGGGACTATCGCTGTTCTCCATACTATTACCCTCCATCTTTAATATTCATTCCTCTAGAACCTCCTGACCAAAATCTGTATTCGTCAGGGTTCTCTAGAGGATAGAACTAATAGGATAGATGTAGATAGAAAGGGAAGTTTATCAAGGGAGTACTGACTCACACGATCATAAGGTGAGGTCCCACTTTTGAGTAGGCCATCTGCAAGCACTGAGGAGCAAGGGTCCAGTAGGAGTCTCACAGCTGAAGAAGTTGGGTTTGATGTTCGAGGGCAGGAAGCATCCAGCATGGGAGAAATATGTAGGCCACAAAGATTAAACCAGTCTAGTCTTTCCATGTGTTTCTTCTCCTGCTTTTGTGGAGTCCTTGCTGGCAGCTGATTGAGGGTAGGTCTCGTTTCCAGTCCCACTGACTCAAATGTTAATCTCCCGGCAACACCCTCGCAGACACACTAAAGAACAATACCTTGCATCCTTCAATCCAATGAAGGTGACACTCAATATTAACCATCACAATAACTAATACGTTTTTATAGGGAATAAAGCACATATTTCCCATGATACCTGTAGAATTGTGTTTCTCTGGCCTGAATATAGGTTGGATTGGTTTAAATGTGAATTTTGTTTTACAATATTTATATGTCAATTGTAAATTCTGAGCACTTTCGAGTCAGAGCATACCTTTTTTTGAGATGGAGTCTCGCTCTGTCACCTAGGCTGGAGTGCAGTGGTGTGATCTCAGCTAGCTGCAACCTCCACCTCCTCAGGTTCAAGCGATTCTCCTGCCTGAGCCCCTGCCGAGCAGTTGGGATTACAGGTGCCCACCACCACATCTGGCTAATTTTGAAATTTTGAGACGGGGTTTCACCACGTGGGCCAGGCTGGTTTGAACTCCTGACCCCAGGTGATCCACCCGCCTCAGCTTCCCAAAGTGCTGGGATTACAGTGTGAGCCGCCGCCTGGCCAAATCATTACTTTTGAAGAAATAGTTAACAATGATTATTTCTTTTTGAATGACAATAAATTTTATTAATAAGTTAAACATATTTATATGTAATGTAAATTTTTGTATCCGGGTGCAGTAGTTCTTGCCCGTTATCCTAGCACTTTGGGAGGCCAAGGTGTTAATATTGCTTGAGCAGGAGTTTGAGACCAGCCTGGGAAACATGGTGAAACCTCATATCTACAAAAAATACAGCCTGGTGTT
>318cae4a-c764-4fe0-97b3-720b49f2bd80
TCGTGCGCTGCGTTCGTTCGTATTGCTGTTTTCTGACTTTACATCTTCGTAACGCTCGCGTTCGTGCGCCGCTAAGGCCAATAACAGGCTGAAATTGAGCCAATAATTAATAGCTTGCAACCAAAAAAGTCTGGGATTAAGCACATTACAATAGCCAACTACACAGGCTGAGAGGGAGAAGCTGGTACCACTCGCTAAAACTATTCTAATCAGTAGAAAAAGGGGAATACTCCTAGCTCATTTATGGGGCGGCATCATCTGATACCAACGCCTGGCAGAGACACAACAAAAGAGAAATTTTAGACCAATATCTGATGAAGAGACATGGTGCAAAAATCCTCAATAAATGCTGTGACCAAGATCAGCATCAAGCATCCACCATGAGTCAAGTGGGCTTCATCCTGGGATGCAAGGCTATTTCAACTATGCAAATCAATAAACAGTAATCAACATAAACAGGGCAAAGACAAAGAAACACACATGATTATCTCAATAGATGCAGAAAGGCCTTAAGACAAAATTCAAAGCAACCGCTTCATACTAAAAACTCTCAATAAATTAGGTATGATGATGGGACCTTATCTCAAAGTAATGGAGCTATTTATGACAAACCCACGTATCATACTGAATGAGCAAAAAACTGGAGAGAGTGTTCCCTTTAGCTTGGCACAAAGAACAAGGATGCCCTCTCTCACACACTCCCTATTCAGCCTTAGTGTTGGAAGTTCTGGCCAGGGCCATCGAGCCGAAGAAGAAATAAAGATTATTCAATTAGGAAAAAGAAAAGTCAAATTCTGTTTGAATGAGCAGCAGTCATATCTGAAAACCCCATGTGATCTCATTCCCCAAAATATCCTTAGCTGATAGCTTAACTAAAGTCTCAGGATACAAAATCAATGTTTGCAAAAATCTAGGGCAGATAACATACACTAATAGCAGAAGCAGGAGGCAAATCATGAGTGAACTCCATTCTGAGAATTGCTTTCAAAGAGAATCAAATACGGGAATCCAACTTACAGGGATGTGGGACCTCTTCAAGGAGAACAGAAACCACTAACTCATATAATAAAGAGGATGCAAACAAATGGAAGAGCATTCCCATGCTCATGGATCAGGAAGAATCAATATCAGTGATAATCCGCCCTACTGCCCATATTAATTACCAGATTCAATACATCCCGTCAAGCTACCAGTGACTTTCTTCTGGAATTGGAAAAACACTTTAAAGGAGGAAGTTCTGTGGAATAAAAGAGCTACCATGCGCCAGAGTCAATCTAAGCCAAAGAACAAAGCCAGAGGCATCATTTACTGACTTTGAAACATACACAGTCTGATACTGGTGCACCAGAACAGGGTTATAGTAATGGAACAGGAGAACTAGGCCCTCAGAAACCACCACACATCTACAACCATCTGATCTTTGACAAACACAAACAAAAACAAGAAATGGGGAAAGGATTCCCTAATATTTA
```

**Input file - 2. some_pattern_file.fasta**

```
>telomere_tract
TTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGG
```

**Conditions:**

1. The read must contain the "TTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGGTTAGGG" pattern at least twice.
2. The last occurrence of the pattern must be located near the read's end (less than 20,000 bases from the end of the read).

************** To summarize: **************

- Input file to the code: subset_na12878dataset.fasta
- Pattern to search for: telomere_tract_pattern.fasta
- Conditions for the location of the pattern in each read: (i) A read must contain the pattern at least twice, (ii) The last occurence of the pattern must be located near the read's end (less than 20,000 bases from the end of the read).
- Code to use for pattern searching: KMP ( https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/kmp-algorithm-for-pattern-searching/ )
- Output file of the code: subset_na12878dataset_telom.fasta (The order of the reads in the output file does not matter, as long as they are all located in the file.)

---

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As with most "Is there a way" questions the answer is yes. I recommend using `std::ifstream`, `std::getline`, and `std::string` to read the file and `std::ofstream` to write the results.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with [`std::ifstream::rdbuf`](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/rdbuf/).

```
char *const buffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
std::filebuf* pFileBuffer = inputFile.rdbuf();
pFileBuffer->sgetn(buffer,size);
```

Don't forget that this operation copies the content to the array you've provided. The `char *const` doesn't directly point to the content of the file. Actually, I don't know if there is a sane way to access the file's address directly.